# how to export a constant from child to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got a Percentchange.js file like this,

```
//(Ending price - starting price)/(Starting price) = %change.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

const PercentChange = ({ setData: record }) => {
  const [startPrice, setStartPrice] = useState([]);
  const [endPrice, setEndPrice] = useState([]);

....
  const percentChange = (
    ((endPrice[0] - startPrice[0]) / startPrice[0]) *
    100
  ).toFixed(2);
  // setValue(percentChange)
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>{record}</h2>
        {/* {percentChange >= 0 ? setColour("green") : setColour("red")} */}
        <h2 style={{ color: percentChange < 0 ? "red" : "green" }}>
          {percentChange({ value: percentChange })}%
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PercentChange;
```

I want to pass the const percentChange from this file

```
const percentChange = (
    ((endPrice[0] - startPrice[0]) / startPrice[0]) *
    100
  ).toFixed(2);
```

to another Search.js file.
is it possible to export a const value from child to child in react?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution will be to use Redux/Context check the links below.
You will need it for sure in the future

[Redux](https://redux.js.org/)
[Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `percentChange` in various files, define that `const` on the global scope and export it just like you did with `PercentChange`

```
//(Ending price - starting price)/(Starting price) = %change.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

const percentChange = (
    ((endPrice[0] - startPrice[0]) / startPrice[0]) *
    100
  ).toFixed(2);

const PercentChange = ({ setData: record }) => {
  const [startPrice, setStartPrice] = useState([]);
  const [endPrice, setEndPrice] = useState([]);

....
  
  // setValue(percentChange)
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>{record}</h2>
        {/* {percentChange >= 0 ? setColour("green") : setColour("red")} */}
        <h2 style={{ color: percentChange < 0 ? "red" : "green" }}>
          {percentChange({ value: percentChange })}%
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PercentChange;

export default percentChange;
```